# jquery remove add classes on hover

Tags: jquery, class, call

Alright so i found a code and it seems to be working but I need to add something to that code to prevent it from firing if I hover over its child menu/sub-menu element but still needs to fire when i hover over other items or other items childern menu's this is the current script

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
   $("#navbar li:hover, #navbar li:sfhover").hover(function(){     
       $('#navbar .current-menu-parent, #navbar li.current-menu-item').addClass("non-ahover");    
   },     
   function(){    
       $('#navbar li.current-menu-parent, #navbar li.current-menu-item').removeClass("non-ahover");     
    });
});
```

So my current active menu would have either the .current-menu-parent or .current-menu-item. my sub menu starts with a < ul > class inside of the parent's < li > class and the sub-menus class is < ul class="sub-menu" > then proceeds with < li > classes for its items.

So my problem is when i hover over my sub-menu that is active by one of its items being the current page or by the parent page being viewed the script above fires and causes ugliness is there a snippet of code i can put inside of this script that stop the call if the current sub-menu is visible so it does not apply the class the script wants to apply?

I know might be a little confusing but if you need clarification at all please let me know and i will help as best as i can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Bind an event handler to the children
2. Have that handler call stopPropagation()

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: do you think you can add it to the code for me i am new to all of this and have learned a lot over the last few hours to even days on this project of mine

Comment: $(".submenu").hover(function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); });

Comment: ok and does that go into the current script or outside if inside where abouts

Comment: inside the anonymous function you passed to $(document).ready() in your example

Comment: ok so i have been trying this a few different ways and its either me or the code but i can not figure it out i have put it in 4 spots before the `**(HERE)** $(document).ready(function() {` and after it `$(document).ready(function() { **(HERE)**` as well as after `$('#navbar .current-menu-parent, #navbar li.current-menu-item').addClass("non-ahover");    
   }, **(HERE)**` and after `$('#navbar li.current-menu-parent, #navbar li.current-menu-item').removeClass("non-ahover"); **(HERE)**` it just does not work the parent is higher then the submenu so i am not sure if that matters or not

Comment: Try reading the comments in the jquery docs.  There are some other suggestions there.  http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: it worked on another page of mine so i am going to look into seeing if there is something stoping it but ill give you the cred